# Does the following limit converges for some value of $a,b>0$?

Tags: limits

How to compute the following limit?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nj^a\exp(j^b)}{n^a\exp(n^b)}$$

What is the range of possible values of $a,b$ for this to hold?

Answer (score 1):

If $b > 1$ then the limit equals $1$ because the last term of your summation will dominate the sum in the numerator, which is equal to the term in the denominator.

Comment: I fail to see this... What happens if $b\leq 1$? For example $1\geq b>0$

Comment: @Laimond If $b = 1$, then since $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^a e^{n^b} / (n-1)^ae^{(n-1)^b} = e$, you will get something like $1 + 1/e + 1/e^2 \cdots$ as the limit. That might even be the exact answer. For $b < 1$, I'm not sure but the limit may be $\infty$.